# How to get a div to be in the same place irrespective of browser?

Tags: html, css

How do a get a div to be in the same place no matter what the users screen size is. I notice when a view my code on a different computer with a bigger screen that my div (with an image) is not in the same place as it was on my laptop, is there any way to make it sit in the same place not matter the browser?

Here is my code

```css
#pic {
  padding-left: 300px;
}
#about {
  padding-left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 100px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  font-size: 120.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pic">

  <img class="errorimage" src="IMG_4847.png" alt="" title="">
  </a>

</div>


<div id="about">


  <h1>Rebekah</h1>


  <h2>Web Design. Google Adwords. Google Analytics.</h2>

</div>
```

Comment: You are missing an opening `a` tag around your image (you just have a closing one) and the formatting is very... spacious.

Comment: The answer will very much depend on whether you have a relative position in mind (i.e. *centred*) or whether you have an absolute position in mind (i.e. *40 pixels from the right edge of the screen*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` to have it in a fixed position no matter scaling

Also `position:fixed` will keep it in the same location in the window even while scrolling

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Then use `position:absolute`

Comment: @becky So what? It was just added for completeness sake, which is good when it comes to Stack Overflow answers.

Comment: I feel like the more appropriate answer here would be to use responsive design with percentages rather than fixing something to the DOM in hopes of it staying there.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast You are allowed to add your own answer

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I understand, but to be honest, this is_exactly_ the question where she is not asking about responsive design - she _wants_ it to be unresponsive (cf. "no matter what the users screen size is"). Delving into responsiveness here might be a bit too much for the question that was asked.